# How to create a chapter without heading and without entry in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I use the following custom command to create a chapter without headings. But it creates a numbered entry in the TOC.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapternoheading}[1]{
  \begingroup
  \let\@makechapterhead\@gobble
  \chapter{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

How do I modify the above so that there is no entry produced in the TOC too? (i.e chapter with no heading and no entry in the TOC)

Comment: What do you mean by a chapter without a heading and without an entry in the table of contents? Just a new page and some space if necessary? That would be `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` + `\vspace*{...}` or `\chapter*{}`. Maybe you could explain a little bit more, what it should be. Also you should give us much more information, e.g., about the used class etc.

Comment: (1) Add a minimal working  example (i.e., the shortest possible document than can be compiled "as is")  with all the elements that should change (e.g., the ToC) but also any elements that *should* not change, e.g.:  float captions? cross-references to the chapter? header in top margin? next normal chapter? ...? ...? ... (2) Be sure that you explain clearly the final objective and not only the problem that you have with the approach that you guessed (xy problem?)